# How to create a basic OpenMRS HTMLFormEntry Form

Tags: forms, openmrs

HTMLFormEntry is a very effective way of saving forms. You create the XML and the module handles transforming the input into database records upon pressing submit.

How can we render a form, e.g. at `path/to/form.xml`?

Do we have to render it in its own page or can we load it into a page?

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Create a new form object from your xml

**Option 1**: Utilizing [`public void HtmlFormEntry.HtmlForm.setXmlData(String xmlData)`](https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-module-htmlformentry/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/openmrs/module/htmlformentry/HtmlForm.java#L97-L99)

```
import org.openmrs.module.htmlformentry.HtmlForm;

...

HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
form.setXmlData(xml);
```

**Option 2**: if your XML is not loaded yet, utilizing [`public static HtmlForm HtmlFormEntryUI.HtmlFormUtil.getHtmlFormFromUiResource(<arguments>)`](https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-module-htmlformentryui/blob/7160eb23c7f893152cfedd750f1cbf4f8673125c/api/src/main/java/org/openmrs/module/htmlformentryui/HtmlFormUtil.java), [reference](https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-module-referenceapplication/blob/0b91f84f7e3005be5dbc14e31966229a239fd361/api/src/main/java/org/openmrs/module/referenceapplication/ReferenceApplicationActivator.java#L198-L221)

- Note: `relativeWebResourcePath` is the relative path from the directory `/omod/src/main/webapp/resources` of your module.
- Arguments are `ResourceFactory resourceFactory, FormService formService, HtmlFormEntryService htmlFormEntryService, String providerAndPath`

```
import org.openmrs.api.FormService;
import org.openmrs.module.htmlformentry.HtmlFormEntryService;
import org.openmrs.module.htmlformentry.HtmlForm;
import org.openmrs.module.htmlformentryui.HtmlFormUtil;

...

String htmlFormPath = thisModuleName+":"+relativeWebResourcePath;
ResourceFactory resourceFactory = ResourceFactory.getInstance();
FormService formService = Context.getFormService();
HtmlFormEntryService htmlFormEntryService = Context.getService(HtmlFormEntryService.class);
HtmlForm form = HtmlFormUtil.getHtmlFormFromUiResource(resourceFactory, formService, htmlFormEntryService, htmlFormPath);
```

### 2. Use [FormEntrySession](https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-module-htmlformentry/blob/f95c76214d682bc6df33b7ffdb2c8b9d413d5b27/api/src/main/java/org/openmrs/module/htmlformentry/FormEntrySession.java) to generate HTML and handle form entry, submission, etc

- [reference](https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-module-htmlformentry/blob/f95c76214d682bc6df33b7ffdb2c8b9d413d5b27/omod/src/main/java/org/openmrs/module/htmlformentry/web/controller/HtmlFormFromFileController.java#L93-L94)
- [better reference](https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-module-htmlformentry/blob/f95c76214d682bc6df33b7ffdb2c8b9d413d5b27/api/src/main/java/org/openmrs/module/htmlformentry/FormEntrySession.java#L260-L262)

```
import org.openmrs.module.htmlformentry.FormEntrySession;

...

FormEntrySession fes = new FormEntrySession(patient, form, request.session)
String html = fes.getHtmlToDisplay()
```

### 3. Use the html generated

The html that the `FormEntrySession` object generated should contain all the logic required to submit the form.